# Emacs Whitespace Mode ignores whitespace-line-column and fill-column

Tags: emacs, whitespace, emacs24

I have an issue using Emacs 24.1.1 on Mac OS X.  I'm editing Jade and CoffeeScript files, so I've turned on whitespace-mode for those file types.

What I'm seeing is that lines longer than 70 characters are highlighted with the whitespace-line font face, regardless of the setting of whitespace-line-column.

[image: screen shot of problem]

In this shot, it is clear that I've customized whitespace-line-column to track fill-column, and I've set fill-column to 120, but much shorter lines are being highlighted.

I've glanced over the code for the Jade mode and don't see anything that would explain the behavior, but I have only a passing understanding of Emacs Lisp.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: `fill-column` is buffer local.  Can you confirm it's 120 in your `user.jade` buffer by typing `M-: fill-column` while it's the current buffer?

Comment: ^H v fill-column


fill-column is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is 120
Original value was 70
Local in buffer index.jade; global value is 70

Comment: It's looking like whitespace mode only honors the global alue for fill-column; it doesn't seem to be aware of the buffer-local version.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set `whitespace-line-column` *before* you activate `whitespace-mode`. That is, if you want to change its value it does not take effect unless you turn `whitespace-mode` off and on again. Ironically, that variable is not available for `M-x customize` until you have activated the mode once :-(

However, you can customize the global value of this variable by putting the following line in your .emacs file:

```
(setq whitespace-line-column 120)
```

Since your .emacs is evaluated when you start Emacs, the setting will take effect before you invoke whitespace-mode for the first time and should thus do what you want. If you don't want to set the value globally, but only for Jade files, put the following in your .emacs file instead:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'whitespace-line-column) 80)
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          '(lambda () (when (eq major-mode 'jade-mode)
                        (setq whitespace-line-column 120))))
```

If you never want long lines to be highlighted specially at all, there is a third option you might want to consider. You could customize the variable whitespace-style (by typing `M-x customize-variable` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `whitespace-style` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and in the value list remove the entries:

- lines
- lines-tail

(if any). This should turn off highlighting of long lines globally independent of the value of `whitespace-line-column` (again, only after you de- and re-activate whitespace mode).

Comment: Would you consider this a bug?  It seems to me that whitespace mode should honor whitespace-line-column (and fill-columns) whenever it changes.